# Get list of local and domain/remote users that are logged in

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

On Windows Server 2008 R2, I want to know which users are logged in remotely (and locally) to this computer.

For example, the Windows Server is on subnet 192.169.34.xxx and I am accessing folders on the server, from my PC (which is on domain: 192.169.32.xxx). I get access to the Server via Windows Explorer like follows:

```
\\191.169.34.55\d$
```

Then it asks me for username and password: Username I use serverDomain\admin and then the password for the admin user account on the server.

So my Question: When I access the server like that, how can I, from the server, see which users are accessing the server remotely like I do from my local PC from a different subnet (or from the same subnet if any)

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to list the user they connected to your Server you can type this command local:

```
NET SESSION | FIND "\\"
```

Or if you search for a remote command try this:

```
PSEXEC \\191.169.34.55 NET SESSION | FIND "\\"
```

You can add some Expressions to the find command to filter the output for your optimal result.

Comment: thank you, works great. What other options are avail for "" apart from \\ ?

Comment: You can set a expression for specially your UNC Share, so if there are more than one share you can filter for only the one your interested

Comment: ok cool, appreciated.